# How can I use getline without blocking for input?

Tags: c++, nonblocking, getline

Is there any method to call `getline()` and, if there is no input given, not to block and waiting?

I have the following code:

```
 while(true){
    if(recv(sd, tBuffer, sizeof(tBuffer), MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) > 0) break;
    getline(cin,send);
 }
```

I want to wait for an input, but if I receive some data at `sd` socket, I want stop waiting for the data and exit the `while`. My code right now, just stucks on first iteration at `getline()`. I want to evaluate `getline()`, and if is no input available, go back at `if`.

Is this possible?

PS: I tried with `cin.peek()`, but that blocks for input too.

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, it is possible. At least on Linux.

Comment: I`m using Ubuntu.. How is that possible ? Can you give me some links or explain to me ?

Comment: The short answer is: 1) Use low-level I/O, not `getline`. 2) Use `select`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting non-blocking mode on standard input, file descriptor 0:

```
int flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now, if there's no input available, the underlying `read()` system call will return 0, and `std::cin` will think that this is end of file, and set `eof()` on `std::cin`.

When you wish to read from standard input again, just `clear()` the stream's state.

The only complicating factor here is that this makes it difficult to detect a real end-of-file condition on `std::cin`. Not much a problem when standard input is an interactive terminal; but if standard input can be a file this is going to be an issue.

In that case, your only realistic option is to forego `std::cin` completely, put non-blocking mode on file descriptor 0, `poll()` or `select()` it, to determine when there's something to read, then `read()` it.

Although you could also use `poll()` or `select()` with `std::cin`, this is going to get complicated, because you will need to explicitly check if there's anything already buffered in `std::cin`'s `streambuf`, because that would, obviously, preempt any kind of `poll()` or `select()` checking; but by attempting to read something from `std::cin`, you still run the risk of reading the buffered data, then attempting to `read()` from the underlying file descriptor that's now in non-blocking mode, this resulting in a fake end-of-file condition.

To summarize: you need invest some additional time reading and understanding how file streams, and stream buffers work; and how file descriptors actually work, and how non-blocking mode works; in order to figure out the correct logic you will need to use.

Oh, and if you insist on going the non-blocking route with `std::cin`, and `getline()`, you will have no easy way to determine if the string returned by `getline()` ends because `getline()` actually read a newline from standard input, or it reached a premature fake-end of file condition and not the entire line of input has actually been read.

So, with non-blocking mode, and `std::cin`, you'll be pretty much forced to use `read()`, instead of `getline()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [istream::getsome()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/) method can be used to perform non-blocking reads. You can use it to build a non-blocking equivalent of [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

```
bool getline_async(std::istream& is, std::string& str, char delim = '\n') {

    static std::string lineSoFar;
    char inChar;
    int charsRead = 0;
    bool lineRead = false;
    str = "";

    do {
        charsRead = is.readsome(&inChar, 1);
        if (charsRead == 1) {
            // if the delimiter is read then return the string so far
            if (inChar == delim) {
                str = lineSoFar;
                lineSoFar = "";
                lineRead = true;
            } else {  // otherwise add it to the string so far
                lineSoFar.append(1, inChar);
            }
        }
    } while (charsRead != 0 && !lineRead);

    return lineRead;
}
```

This functions works identically to the original `std::getline()` function except it always returns instantly. I've got it on [my gists](https://gist.github.com/PeteBlackerThe3rd/8ab24aa87620625d3b43f58965baf24a) because it comes in handy occasionally.

Comment: This is working somehow only with: `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I used select() to retrieve the status of the stdin file descriptor. This worked on Ubuntu and on an embedded Linux board. If stdin still has not received an enter keystroke from the user, select will wait some time and report that stdin is not ready. stopReading can stop monitoring the stdin and continue on other stuff. You can edit it as needed. It may not work on special input tty's.

```
#include <sys/select.h>

static constexpr int STD_INPUT = 0;
static constexpr __suseconds_t WAIT_BETWEEN_SELECT_US = 250000L;

// Private variable in my class, but define as needed in your project
std::atomic<bool> stopReading;

...

std::string userInput = "";
while (false == stopReading)
{
    struct timeval tv = { 0L, WAIT_BETWEEN_SELECT_US };
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STD_INPUT, &fds);
    int ready = select(STD_INPUT + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (ready > 0)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use @PeteBlackerThe3rd's answer in my own project. Unfortunately I was only able to get it to work when running `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` prior. So I attempted my own version that is also thread safe in case multiple threads are reading from multiple sources.

```
// Returns 1 on success, 0 when not done, and -1 on failure (check errno)
// str is initially expected to be an empty string and should only altered by this function.
int getline_async_thread_safe(const int& fd, std::string& str, char delim = '\n') {
    int chars_read;
    do {
        char buf[2] = { 0 };
        chars_read = (int) read(fd, buf, 1);
        if (chars_read == 1) {
            if (*buf == delim) {
                return 1;
            }
            str.append(buf);
        } else {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                chars_read = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (chars_read > 0);

    return chars_read;
}
```

Example of the function being called:

```
int flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

std::string output;
int retval;
while(some_condition) {
    retval = getline_async_thread_safe(0, output);
    if (retval == 0) {
        // Process std::string output 
        // Make sure to reset string if continuing through loop
    } else if (retval == -1) {
        // Check errno
    }
    // Do other things while waiting for the newline.
}
if (retval < 0) {
    // Handle error with errno.
} else {
    std::cout << "Output: " << output << std::endl;
}
```